# How to change AWS IAM group path?

Tags: amazon-iam

IAM group path is a way to organize groups following an enterprise structure. Looking at the [IAM Console](https://console.aws.amazon.com/iam/home) I cannot find a way to set or modify the path of a group. Is it possible from the console or is there another way programmatically or through the CLI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, you must use the AWS cli or a programming language, e.g,

```
aws iam create-group --path "/company/team/project/" --group-name "your-group"
```

The groups are not listed in the Console in hierarchical form, but the ARN includes the path.

```
arn:aws:iam::111111111:group/company/team/project/your-group
```